# Short for 'for i in range(1,len(a)):' in python

Tags: python, for-loop, range, iteration, enumerate

In python, is there a short way of writing `for i in range(len(l)):`?

I know I can use `for i,_ in enumerate(l):`, but I want to know if there's another way (without the `_`).

Please don't say `for v in l` because I need the indices (for example to compare consecutive values `l[i]==l[i+1]`).

Comment: `for i in range(len(l))` is short enough.

Comment: Is there a short way of writing `for`? ;)

Comment: @EllaShar Come on, it's just that `range(len(l))` is too long in comparison with how frequently I use it. I'ts not like it's terribly long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it shorter by defining a function:

```
def r(lst):
    return range(len(lst))
```

and then:

```
for i in r(l):
    ...
```

Which is 9 characters shorter!

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to compare consecutive elements, you don't need to use indices. You can use `zip()` instead:

```
for el1, el2 in zip(l, l[1:]):
```

Or use `enumerate()` anyway:

```
for el2idx, el1 in enumerate(l[:-1], 1):
    el2 = l[el2idx]
```

If you really must generate *just* and index, then `range(len(l))` is short enough, there is no shorter form.

Comment: Do you think it should exist a shorter form to get the indices?

Comment: @CarlosPinzón: no, for the most part you don't really need to use `range()`, there usually are better alternatives.

Comment: Often there is a better way than using indices, as Martijn has demonstrated here.  If you really need a shorter way, define a function:  `def indices(l): return range(len(l))`

Answer (score -1):

There are use cases for needing to iterate over the indices, but they are not so common as to justify a more succint syntax. Even the example you give, of finding duplicates in a list, is easily (and arguably more readably) done without the indices. For example:

```
it = iter(items)
last = next(items, None)

for item in it:
   if item == last:
       print "Duplicate:", item
       break
   else:
      last = item
else:
   print "No duplicate found."
```

(You can also use `zip()` as Martijn has shown.)